# Donation of Bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty

**EDIT:  The question I linked clearly states "...please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here."  That does not show up on the iPad, and I missed that.  Sorry!**

Stack Exchange has been crucial to my learning.  I would not know half of what little I know if it were not for the wonderful teachers here.  I want to give back to the community, and aside from donating money I don't have, donating a bounty is the next best thing I can think of.

If I asked a question on Stack Exchange that was a contest and awarded a 500 bounty to the answer with the most upvotes, would this be allowed?

For example, if I asked "Write a joke method..." and an example answer would be:

```
public String getTypeOfThing(Thing thing) {
    try {
        return doWhatIExpect(thing);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Feature";
    }
}
```

Something similar to [What is your best programmer joke?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke), although not as awesome.  Preferably something that inexperienced programmers like myself as well as veterans could answer creatively.

Comment: So, I get that if I did this, it would deserve the downvote.  But which part of asking if I can do this deserves the downvote?

Comment: I think that's a pretty silly idea, Keep your rep, and ask questions (maybe canonical tries) that are really useful for future research. I also feel that the question you mentioned would have been closed (as clearly being _opinion based_) nowadays. (Downvotes on meta, are indicating aggrement or not mostly, it was mine and I have specified my reasoning here)

Comment: Did you see the message on the question you linked?  It reads: *"This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here."*

Comment: @iCodez sure didnt :-/ that doesnt show up on the ipad

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are welcome to donate your reputation however you wish, so long as the way you do it still follows the rules of our site.

Creating a contest question like you suggest, not the way to do it. That question would be nowhere near on-topic for our site, and would probably be closed down and deleted swiftly before you even gained an answer.

If you're interested in giving away your reputation as thanks, I would focus on finding the answers which have been *most helpful* in your journey on Stack Overflow and reward those for being so awesome. Why give some random user 500 reputation for a random useless answer when you could reward an honest answer that helped you personally?

Comment: I thought about that too, and honestly, I was expecting this exact answer.  I just thought a contest would be more fun, and figured I would take the long short and ask if I was allowed.